# selenium Getting this error how to resolve

Tags: selenium

Exception in thread `"main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:` 
    The method `id(String)` is undefined for the type `String`

```
at Demo.Registration.main(Registration.java:12)
```

Comment: can you share the script with us where you are using the id(String)

Comment: package newproject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.NullPointerException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.openqa.selenium.webdriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class demo {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\kalyani\\downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\");
ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println("selenium.getPageSource()");
}
}

Answer (score 0):

### **at third last line**

```
System.out.println("selenium.getPageSource()"); .
```

### you don't have to give quotes it has to like

```
String source = selenium.getPageSource();
System.out.println("Page Source :"+source);
```

### or direct also in print statement

```
System.out.println("Page source : "+selenium.getPageSource());
```